# how to tell react-router to wait until something has happened?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, firebase-authentication

I want to configure `react-router` to wait for Firebase to login (or logout) before rendering any route.

I've seen `react-router` has an `onEnter()` hook, but it seems this is an immediate callback, and I haven't quite figured out how I would make `react-router` wait until firebase triggers an `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` event.

Does `react-router` include some functionality to handle such cases?

Comment: this will produce unexpected behavior for your users, its like **simulated loading of  a SSR page**, where the user has to wait till the response comes back and the page displays.. IMO it would be easier to show a **loading indicator** while async actions are happening

Comment: The problem is not showing an indicator or not, but how to tell the router to wait for an auth event

Comment: Please define what you expect for the user, how should it look like, I guess there is no way to let react-router wait for something.. this is a pattern which is not really common, maybe I am wrong, please provide some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onEnter` hook accepts a third parameter, `callback?`, which if specified will block loading of the route until it is called.

An [example from the react-router repo](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow-async-with-query-params/app.js#L60):

```
function requireCredentials(nextState, replace, next) {
  const query = nextState.location.query
  if (query.qsparam) {
    serverAuth(query.qsparam)
    .then(
      () => next(),
      () => {
        replace('/error')
        next()
      }
    )
  } else {
    replace('/error')
    next()
  }
}
```

and the render method:

```
render((
  <Router history={withExampleBasename(browserHistory, __dirname)}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Form} />
      <Route path="page" component={Page} onEnter={requireCredentials}/>
      <Route path="error" component={ErrorPage}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('example'))
```

However, there is a warning about using this for long-running operations [in the documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/112cce48255f930df3270382665223cd41b6f1fa/docs/Glossary.md#enterhook):

> Caution: Using the callback in an enter hook causes the transition to wait until it is called. This can lead to a non-responsive UI if you don't call it very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using a main component in my hierarchy that prevents children to be rendered until something has happened.

[Here is the implementation.](https://gist.github.com/PierBover/220b2f7d5f790158790d3adb55f0a140) Not the most elegant code, but it works in case you are desperate as I was.